# Android read and write data from glucose meter which have cp2103 and bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, serial-port, usbserial, bluetooth-socket

I have an glucose meter VerioSync Which support USB and Bluetooth both. I have protocol for data exchange. Via USB I successfully read data from Meter by sending some commands and receiving data. But via Bluetooth I can scan device and connect it, I can open in and out streams, When I write byte data meter do not send me data or response. Will it work with simple Bluetooth tutorial that google provide or I need to do something special to read data from meter as it have cp2103 chip to convert serial data.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the devices you are going to use are the VerioSync and an Android device. In that case:

The Google tutorial does what you expect it to do: Read data from meter. Serial data is converted by the controller, the host usually has nothing to do with that. Writing on the device is also covered.

So you can use the tutorial. Beware that the tutorial assumes you have the sample project, which you can find by opening Android Studio and going to File -> Import sample. Type in Bluetooth and you will find the sample project.

As to why you might not be getting the values you want; make sure you know if you're dealing with value notifications or indications.